# Tensorflow installation Problem in the Mac m1

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, apple-m1

I faced some problem in the installation of the tensorflow in the mac m1

But followed this documentation https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/  in the resolve the problem

Now able to install tensorflow.

But when  try to change the kernel or python environment which created in VS code

Getting this Error

**`There is no Conda or Pip installer available in the selected environment` **

But clearly I do have pip and conda  installer available

```
pip3 --version

pip 23.1.1
```

trying  to change the kernel or python environment which created using (https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/)  in VS code

Comment: Hi @Sam777, Did you select correct python interpreter in VScode? Please go to settings - Python interpreter  - select created conda VirEnv to set the kernel in VS code IDE. Referring this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_create-or-open-a-jupyter-notebook) might be helpful to you solve this issue